# HTML - Transforms, Animations and other things not working on Android

Tags: html, css

I have a website where I (amongst other things) have a text object which is rotated 45 deg. This is the css I use:

```
.down-arrow-section-text{
    color: var(--color-main); 
    font-family: var(--ff-heading);
    font-size: var(--fs-600);
    //rotate: 5deg;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    animation: MoveUpDown 1s linear infinite;
}
```

It works fine with just the commented out row of `//rotate: 45deg;` but it didn't work on the phone so I added the -moz, -webkit etc to try and make it work on the phone as well. However it is still not rotated 45 degrees on the phone, the text is just as normal text.

The animation is having the same problem, where I tried to create `-wekbit-animation` etc and even give it a `@-webkit-keyframes` but nothing is working.

**How do I get my objects to rotate, translate, animate etc on the phone?**

If it is of any help I use GitHub Pages as temporary host along with my own domain to publish to the internet.

Comment: May I see the demo of this website?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have an Android phone, but it works fine on my iPhone. Have you tried a different browser on an Android phone?

Comment: @PeterK, I added -webkit-transform: -webkit-rotate(5deg); instead which seems to work. But in all other places I am looking they just use -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg);